# how to implement level order print for MaxHeap

Tags: java, tree, heap, tree-traversal

I'm currently making a MaxHeap program and I need to print my heap in level order. How can this be done? Do I create a method to print the heap in level order inside of my heap class or would I do it in my main class? I know for like my binary search tree project i used iterative methods and called them from my main class but I'm not sure if I can do that here. Below is my implementation of the MaxHeap class from my textbook:

```
public final class MaxHeap<T extends Comparable<? super T>> implements MaxHeapInterface<T>
{
private T[] heap;
private int lastIndex;
private boolean initialized = false;
private static final int DEFAULT_CAPACITY = 25;
private static final int MAX_CAPACITY = 10000;

int swaps=0;

public MaxHeap() {
this(DEFAULT_CAPACITY);
}

public MaxHeap(int initialCapacity) {
if (initialCapacity < DEFAULT_CAPACITY)
    initialCapacity = DEFAULT_CAPACITY;
else
    checkCapacity(initialCapacity);

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
T[] tempHeap = (T[]) new Comparable[initialCapacity + 1];
heap = tempHeap;
lastIndex = 0;
initialized = true;
}

public T getMax() {
checkInitialization();
T root = null;
if (!isEmpty())
    root = heap[1];
return root;
}
```